# Migrating Standalone Tomcat Instance to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

Currently I'm just kicking off Tomcat as a daemon from a standalone shell startup script. With that, I have many customized files in my app. For example, the start-up script needs user input, is using modified web.xml and server.xml, etc.

However, it'd be nice to debug the overall application through eclipse. I've loaded up my Eclipse with the capability to build my application, along with the appropriate jre, and the relative tomcat instance on the machine.

How do I configure the tomcat I linked into Eclipse to utilize my custom startup script/ old server.xml/web.xml? There must be configuration for this but it's ill

Thanks

PR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered the Java remote debugging option? This way you could use your current Tomcat setup.

http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t53459.html

Comment: So far so good with the remote debugging. Thanks for the suggestion!